# Statistical mode of a categorical variable in R (using mlv)

Tags: r

I want to calculate the most frequent value of a categorical variable. I tried using the mlv function in the modeest package, but getting NAs.

```
user <- c("A","B","A","A","B","A","B","B")
color <- c("blue","green","blue","blue","green","yellow","pink","blue")
df <- data.frame(user,color)
df$color <- as.factor(df$color)

library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(modeest)

summary <- ddply(df,.(user),summarise,mode=mlv(color,method="mlv")[['M']])

Warning messages:
1: In discrete(x, ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In discrete(x, ...) : NAs introduced by coercion

summary
   user mode
1    A   NA
2    B   NA
```

Whereas, I need this:

```
user  mode
A     blue
B     green
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried using other methods, as well as just `mlv(x=color)`. According to the help pages of [modeest](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/modeest/modeest.pdf), it should work for factors.

I don't want to use table(), as I need a simple function that I can use to create a summary table like in this question: [How to get the mode of a group in summarize in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30385626/how-to-get-the-mode-of-a-group-in-summarize-in-r) ,but for a categorical column.

Comment: Maybe also relevant: [*"Is there a built-in function for finding the mode?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2547402/2204410)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `modeest::mlv.factor()` does not work might actually be a bug in the package.

In the function `mlv.factor()` the function `modeest:::discrete()` is called. In there, this is what happens:

```
f <- factor(color)
[1] blue   green  blue   blue   green  yellow pink   blue  
Levels: blue green pink yellow

tf <- tabulate(f)
[1] 4 2 1 1

as.numeric(levels(f)[tf == max(tf)])
[1] NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

This is what is returned to `mlv.fator()`. But `levels(f)[tf == max(tf)]` equals `[1] "blue"`, hence `as.numeric()` cannot convert it to a number.

You can calculate the mode by finding the unique values and count how many times they appear in a vector. You can then subset the unique values for the one that appears most (i.e. the mode)

Find unique colours:

```
unique_colors <- unique(color)
```

`match(color, unique_colors)` returns the position of the first match of `color` in `unique_colors`. 
`tabulate()` then counts the number of times a color occurs. `which.max()` returns the index of the highest occuring value. This value can then be used to subset the unique colors.

```
unique_colors[which.max(tabulate(match(color, unique_colors)))]
```

Perhaps more readable using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
unique(color)[color %>%
                match(unique(color)) %>% 
                tabulate() %>%
                which.max()]
```

Both options return:

```
[1] blue
Levels: blue green pink yellow
```

EDIT:

The best way is probably to create your own mode-function:

```
calculate_mode <- function(x) {
  uniqx <- unique(x)
  uniqx[which.max(tabulate(match(x, uniqx)))]
}
```

and then use it in `dplyr::summarise()`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(user) %>% 
  summarise(color = calculate_mode(color))
```

Which returns:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
    user  color
  <fctr> <fctr>
1      A   blue
2      B  green
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation! I now understand why mlv doesn't work. However, the example I provided was just a sample problem. I actually want to calculate the mode value for each unique value of another column in my huge database (~1 million samples, 10000 unique values), perhaps using  dplyr::summarise.. Is there something else I could use to calculate the mode in a functional way?

Comment: I have changed the example to be more reflective of my problem.

Comment: Thank you so much Clemens! Will create the function as you suggested. I wanted to avoid doing that, as I felt it may be inefficient, but seems like the only option for now. Strange that a statistical tool like R has no in-built mode calculator.

Comment: Good to hear. You may consider accepting the answer to indicate your question was answered.

Answer (score 3):

You should try `table`. For instance, `which.max(table(color))`.

Comment: Thanks for your tip! This was just a simple example problem. I actually want to calculate the mode value for each unique value of another column in my huge database (~1 million samples, 10000 unique values), perhaps using  dplyr::summarise.. Is there something else I could use to calculate the mode in a functional way?

Comment: I have changed the example to be more reflective of my problem.

Comment: @cantordust I added an answer using dplyr::summarise for your request.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution with dplyr and purrr

you can use a more generalized version of the correct answer by @loudelouk like this:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(user) %>% 
  select_if(is.factor) %>% 
  summarise_all(function(x) { x %>% table %>% which.max %>% names })
```

or shorter:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(user) %>% 
  summarise_if(is.factor, .funs = function(x) { x %>% table %>% which.max %>% names})
```